# How to denote all possible sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Take a sequence ***A***. Imagine a sequence **C**=*(An)n∈J*, where *J ⊆ **U***. **U** is an index set. *J ⊆ **U*** means **J** is a proper subsequence of **U**. Therefore, various possible sequences **C** are denoted by restricting the original sequence **A** to a smaller index set.

When **C** is defined as above, will simply showing the variable **C** inherently signify all possible sequences or just one possible sequence? How can I make sure to formally denote all possible sequences **C** can be? Is there a symbol commonly used for this?

Comment: By $\mathbf J\subseteq \mathbf U$ you mean $\mathbf J$ is a proper subset of $\mathbf U$ or subsequence of $\mathbf U$?

Comment: You need to do some basic proof-reading of your question. You use $An$ for what I suspect is intended to be $A_n$ or $A(n).$ You use italic-light-face *J* and roman-bold-face **J** for apparently the same notion. You use $\subseteq$ (subset with equality allowed) for a **proper** subsequence. That said, I've seen things like ${\text {Subseq}\,{ U}}$ to denote the set of all subsequences of $U$ (including $U$ itself).

Comment: Thanks, where can I find an exhaustive guide to typing out expressions properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have defined $\mathbb A = (A_n)_{n\in \mathbf U}$. Then any subsequence of $\mathbb A$ can be defined as
$$\mathbb C=(A_n)_{n\in \mathbf J},\mathbf J\subseteq \mathbf U$$
The collection of all possible subsequences of $\mathbb A$ is then given as $$\mathcal C=\{(A_n)_{n\in \mathbf J}: \mathbf J\subseteq \mathbf U \}$$

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated